# Memory and CPU impact when a DLL is embedded inside a .NET DLL / EXE?

Tags: .net, performance, dll

We have a DLL we distribute that has external dependencies on other DLLs. Rather than risking missing DLLs or having potential mix-and-matching situations, we embed the DLLs inside our own DLL/EXE and load it at runtime to satisfy runtime linking.

***Question:***

A) Between

- embedding the DLL inside our .EXE/.DLL and then loading it into memory at runtime 
  and
- keeping the DLL as a separate file on the file system and then having the system load it for us

which approach consumes more memory and by approximately how much?

B) Does anyone have a better approach than the above? Especially for item #3 in the *details* below.

---

*Details on our process for the interested:*

1. Register for the AssemblyResolve event at a portion that we know runs before the code in the assembly is called (eg: init time)

   ```
   public void SomeInitCode()
   {
       ...
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
       {
           string[] assemblyDetail = args.Name.Split(',');
           var assemblyName= assemblyDetail[0] + ".dll";

           var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           var allResourceNames = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

           string requiredResName = allResourceNames.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EndsWith(assemblyName));

           using (var input = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(requiredResName))
           {
               return input != null
                    ? Assembly.Load(StreamToBytes(input))
                    : null;
           }
       };
       ...
   }

   static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream input)
   {
       var capacity = input.CanSeek ? (int)input.Length : 0;
       using (var output = new MemoryStream(capacity))
       {
           int readLength;
           var buffer = new byte[4096];

           do
           {
               readLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               output.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
           }
           while (readLength != 0);

           return output.ToArray();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Embed the assembly. This is done by "Add existing item" to the .NET project => pick the .dll => ok. Go back and pick the .dll and in properties change the "Build action" to "Embedded Resource".
3. We still have to add the same .DLL as a reference and still need to have the `using ExternalNamespace;` statements on the top of classes using it. If not, build process fails since it can't see the external DLL code at compile time. So as a post-build action, we have to delete the .DLL file (not it's embedded clone) from the final `bin` folder.

Comment: Anonymous `close` voter: At least speak up.

Comment: You couldn't have your installer handle the dependencies?

Comment: Good point, however, this is a standalone no-install distribution for developers

Comment: I would just ILMerge everything together :)

Comment: @leppie you should add that as an answer - it could be an ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: as long as the inner assembly doesn't itself have some huge size (some massive embedded resource, for example) it should work *acceptably* - that is a bit of a wriggly answer, but I don't have a better one other than "measure it". I've done very similar things occasionally (and for similar reasons).

B: set "Copy Local" on the reference properties (<kbd>f4</kbd>) to `False`. You would need the `using ExternalNamespace;` even if the files were in the same project - that just brings the namespace into play.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Marc.

I would just use ILMerge to throw everything together.

It might however not be possible, but should work for 'pure' managed assemblies (including ones using `unsafe`).