# Accessing an Oracle DB via C# without forcing the user to install an Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm using the oracle.dataaccess.dll when having to query an Oracle DB. But it doesn't work if the user doesn't have an Oracle client installed on his machine. Is it possible to somehow include the Oracle client inside a dll so the user won't have to explicitly install the client?

Comment: Well, sometimes you can [embed it or merge it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15823842/23354), but usually you can just ship the library dll with your project - does that not suffice?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't suffice with Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ship the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) with your application.

This is a complete Oracle client but it doesn't require installation, it can be used directly.

However, you need to be aware of the following:

1. The instant client is over 120 MB in size.
2. You need *different* versions of the instant client for x86 and x64, bringing the size to about 250 MB.

The advantage of using the instant client is that you don't have to worry about the installed version of the Oracle client. Even if the computer already has an incompatible version installed, your application will work, because it comes with the correct version.

Comment: can anyone guide me how to "ship" with my application ? its a asp.net application with C# back end

Comment: as I developed my application having a dependency on Oracle.DataAccess.dll, will it require any code change ?

Answer (score 5):

[The managed ODP.net client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) is exactly what you want. Now that there's a 12c version out, it's a simple single assembly that you can deploy with your application and not have to worry about Oracle installations.

[There's also a nuget package that you can use if you don't want to install on your system.](https://twitter.com/OracleDOTNET/status/556251239294332929) That is very painless to get up and running. Here's some links to those:

- [Main package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)
- [Second package to use Entity Framework 6/Code First](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)

Comment: @Zenadix Should work now, Oracle moves around their download pages so I went to the main one instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to pay, I've had fair success with DevArt's [DotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) as an alternative to the client provided by Oracle.

It provides a completely managed way of connecting to and querying Oracle, along with Entity framework & nHibernate support and emulation for `GUIDs`, `booleans` and a few other datatypes where Oracle lacks support (`GUID` is `raw(16)` in Oracle).

All you have to do is ship a single managed DLL with your project.

Comment: I think you mean System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is in .Net4. I hadn't heard of `System.Data.OracleClient`, is it packaged with .Net?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is the one provided by Microsoft in the framework, and is the depreciated one. Oracle.DataAccess is the one provided by Oracle for .net 2 and 4, and is not depreciated. (Oracle's client also has EF support now, and a beta of a managed client that's a single dll with no installation.)

Comment: Tridus is right. Oracle.DataAccess.Client is not part of the .NET framework. It is provided by Oracle and is only a managed wrapper around the unmanaged Oracle DLLs.

Comment: I've removed the offending data :) Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by making the Oracle connection string in my app.config and copying all the client DLL's as in this picture:

[image: DLL's I COPIED]